# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string-matching

I am having a weird issue with Python. For some reason, when I call it from the command line, I can use the replace() function as much as I want but I cannot use it inside a specific class. The code yields the following (well-known) error:

```
    File "/homes/mmj11/malice/lexer.py", line 96, in replaceInTree
    tree[i] = tree[i].replace("  "," ")
    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The function I'm using is the following:

```
   def replaceInTree(self, tree):
    for i in range(len(tree)):
      if type(tree[i] is str):
         tree[i] = tree[i].replace("  "," ")
         tree[i] = tree[i].replace(tree[i], self.getToken(tree[i]))
      else:
         tree[i] = self.replaceInTree(tree)
    return tree
```

I really think this should not happen as I can do the exact same thing in the command line. I am very sure that str's are meant to be callable.

Comment: "I am very sure that str's are meant to be callable." No.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
 if type(tree[i] is str):
```

Dont you mean to do

```
 if type(tree[i]) is str:
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. It's weird how it reported an error on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
if type(tree[i]) is str:
```

instead of this:

```
if type(tree[i] is str):
```

The way you have it written evaluates to `if type(false)`, which is equivalent to `if bool`, which will always be truthy.